# How to validate every object and key values of json

Tags: java, json

I need to validate this JSON in the following method.

```
{
  "DOG":{
 "displayName":"DOGGY",
 "description":"Has for legs",
 "classification":"Lab"
  },
"CAT":{
 "displayName":"CATHY",
 "description":"Has for legs",
 "classification":"xxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Now I need to validate the above json by validating each fields suchs as

1. displayName
2. description
3. classification
4. And also get key such as DOG, CAT

Now the above things should be validating.
But I am unable to get the keys such as DOG, CAT.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(useCase.asString());
        Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();
        Map<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        Map<Object, Object> anotherMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        while(keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                myMap.put(((JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key)).getString("displayName")), ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key)).getString("classification"));
            }
        }

        anotherMap.forEach((k, v) -> myMap.put(k.toString(), v.toString()));

        myMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));*/
```

Goal is to validate it against json response.

Comment: `jsonObject.keys()` this will have the values DOG, CAT

Comment: No its not giving key values

Comment: what values are it giving?

Comment: The array iterators instead of dogs and cat

Comment: you should double check your output. and for me I'm getting the output as CAT, DOG. can you post the exact data in `usecase`

Comment: ```System.out.println(jsonObject.keys().toString());``` output- ```java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator@36bc415e```

Comment: you can't print iterator instead you can use `System.out.println(jsonObject.keySet());` or you can use `jsonObject.keys().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218257/discussion-between-sobhit-sharma-and-deadshot).

Comment: You could take a look at the following sample of JSON validation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350063/how-to-check-empty-element-in-json/61441827#61441827